# Why does Jenkins double the total amount of tests if the build is successfull?

Tags: c++, jenkins-plugins, googletest, xunit

I have set up a Jenkins server and I set up a project (c++) that uses googletest, xUnit and cobertura. It calculates a the test-coverage, and my tests passes as well. I did it all in one single shell script.

Now my problem is, if all tests pass I have a total amount of e.g. 20 items. If a single test item fail, I only have 10 items in total (total=passed+skipped+fail).

When I check a successful build details, for instance, I click on :"last stable build...", "Test Result", "root", "foo" then I am on a page "Test Result: foo" below a table with "All tests", containing 2 rows of "foo".
I I do the same for a failed build, I only have 1 item in this list. Somehow here the factor 2 comes from.

I'd like to know why it's count different and where is my mistake? IMHO I would assume both would only contain one item.

Comment: We'd need to see your shell script, at the very least.

Comment: I believe my shell is not the issue, anyway:
cd /home/share/projects/foo/build
rm -rf ./*
cmake ..
make clean
make all

test/unitTest/foo1_unittest --gtest_output=xml:../workspace/foo1-test-results.junit.xml
cd test/unitTest/CMakeFiles/foo1_unittest.dir
gcov -abcfo . *
cd ../../../..

test/unitTest/foo2_unittest --gtest_output=xml:../workspace/foo2-test-results.junit.xml
cd test/unitTest/CMakeFiles/foo2_unittest.dir
gcov -abcfo . *
cd ../../../..

# ...and some more ...

gcovr -v -b -u -d -e '/usr/' -e '/gtest*' -e 'abc' -e '/def' -x --xml-pretty -o ../workspace/coverage.info

Comment: I didn't mange to get CRLF working in my post, sorry.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) how to format code in the body of a post. Relevant info needs to be there, not in comments, or answers are unlikely. Even so I'm afraid I think there is little chance that you can make this problem reproducible in a post.